# Ubuntu, battery is never fully charged

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, battery, acpi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a Lenovo thinkpad e550 and i have a problem: the battery doesn't charge, the icon on the panel doesn't indicate it's charging, and in "Power Statistics" -> "Laptop Battery" state is "discharging".

This laptop hasn't been used for some months, if that helps. Any idea?

EDIT:
I let the computer fully discharge. I was then able to charge it with no problems. Now I'm back at 100% and even if the power adapter is connected,   the battery is still discharging and in the panel the indicator says "19:48 left".

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct power adapter?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure...

Answer (score 1):

Probably batery just died, there's no way that an `os` would lead into a batery not charging.

Comment: I'm at 78% right now, with 4:16 left...

Comment: I would be on my way to a shop...